# How to pass parameter to class php with jQuery .ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the next class php:

```
class Job{

    public $resultado;
    public $busqueda;
    public $wpdb;

    public function __construct($busqueda){
        global $wpdb;
        $this->busqueda = $busqueda;
        $this->resultado = array();
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    }   

    public function search_job($resultado){
        $tablepost =$this->wpdb->prefix.'posts';
        $query = "SELECT * from $tablepost WHERE post_type = 'jobman_job' and post_status='publish';";



        if (isset($wpdb)) {
            global $wpdb;
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        }else{
            $result = $this->wpdb->get_results($query);
        }



        print_r($result);
    }

}
```

This found ok. Now I would like call the search_function with jQuery .ajax
I try with this:

```
(function($){

    $('#searchjob').keypress(function(e){
        var search = $.trim($('#searchjob').val());

        if (e.which == "13") {

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    //$('#loading').html(<img src="rutagif" alt="loading" />);
                },
                url:"../wp-content/themes/SUP2012/class/job.php",
                data:{method: 'search_job', data:{resultado: 'hola'}},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){

                }

            }); 
        };

    });

 })(jQuery);
```

the url parameters respond ok (200 OK), but not retrive information. Any idea?

Comment: I checked the information through firebug but the response is blank

Comment: you have just call the php file but you want have specified how your class will initialize and method will be called

Comment: How did you initialize the class or you didn't ?

Comment: what is beforeSend and why have you defined this inside ajax call

Comment: @rajeshkakawat sorry I don't understand, my english is not very well.

Comment: It looks like wordpress, am I right ? If so then you are totally doing it wrong.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I could to do changes in the class for that I didn't initialize the class.

Comment: @refhat beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)Function

A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes, this is wordpress. Why is wrong ?

Comment: [Check this cool thing](http://wpajax.s3.amazonaws.com/2ndedition/wp-ajax-book.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJHNMGJCAUGWHDBMQ&Expires=1350709806&Signature=4i197sxTsVUj1DpH2fZNMPma0JQ%3D).

Comment: @SheikhHeera thank a lot for the book. But independently there are some form that jQuery .ajax send parameters to class php?. Any example ?

Comment: Do you want to get a custom post type(jobman_job) using ajax ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes I want to get cutom post type information, in fact when I call to class directly, this retrieve data, but I don't know retrieve data through jQuery .ajax calling class PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an `ajax` request in `wordpress` you should use in `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function_name', 'your_function_name');
add_action('wp_ajax_your_function_name', 'your_function_name');
function your_function_name()
{
    // do anything here and echo the result
    $data_from_ajax=$_POST['data_to_send_to_server'];
    die(); // last line 
}
```

And the javascript should look like

```
$('#searchjob').keypress(function(e){
    var your_data = $.trim($(this).val());
    if (e.which == "13") {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // if this file is in a subfolder in your themes folder
            data: {
                action:'your_function_name', // the function name you used in functions.php
                data_to_send_to_server:your_data // retrieve from $_POST in php
            },
            success:function(data){
                // do something with data
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have just try out the code and work very good!. I'm working with wordpress and a custom template on wordpress! :D.